Palmprint recognition with gabor and CNN
I'm using gabor filter on ROI (region of interest) images then I'm putting them on the CNN model. Is this code right for CNN and palmprint recognition?
# Define Gabor filters
def build_filters():
    filters = []
    ksize = 11
    for theta in range(4):
        theta = np.pi * (theta / 4)
        for sigma in (1, 3, 5, 7, 9) :
            for lambd in np.arange(0, np.pi, np.pi / 4):
                for gamma in (0.05, 0.3):
                    kern = cv2.getGaborKernel((ksize, ksize), sigma, theta, lambd, gamma, 0.4, ktype=cv2.CV_32F)
                    kern /= 1.5 * kern.sum()
                    filters.append(kern)
    return filters

# Apply Gabor filters to the image
def process(img, filters):
    accum = np.zeros_like(img)
    for kern in filters:
        fimg = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8UC3, kern)
        np.maximum(accum, fimg, accum)
    return accum

I'm putting the result returned from process method on the CNN model.

Welcome to [so]. We don't provide generalized debugging services. We can assist with specific issues. Please use the following references on debugging your code to narrow your problem to a specific issue. How to debug small programs, Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers
